# Swiping activities after ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager

first of all, sorry for the awful question title.

i have a custom ListView filled with questions which are parsed from a xml file. after clicking one of the questions, a new activity is started with the possibility to answer the question. the questions have different types of answers like open text, multiple choice, slider... every answer type has an activity.
after answering the questions, the user presses the okay button and returns to the ListView.

this works so far

however, i would like to add swiping. the user clicks a question in the ListView, answers it and can swipe to the next question or the one before.

what is the best way to implement that? 
keeping my answer activities and use gesture detector to switch between them?
converting my answer activities into fragments and use a ViewPager?

EDIT: a big problem is probably that the questions and therefore the answer types (activies) are always different and not static.

Comment: Converting your answer activities into fragments and use a ViewPager is by far the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create an ArrayList of Intents to be used and call the Activities on based on those intents, Add intents to the ArrayList when the ListView is populated